# Timed annotation micrometer does not work

Tags: spring, spring-boot, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator, spring-micrometer

I have this code:

```
@Timed(value = "kafka.consumed.messages")
@KafkaListener...
public void consume(...)
```

But I doesn't see this metric in prometheus, but I also have a Timer, which is shown in prometheus, how can I fixe it?

Comment: Yes @Timed does not work on kafka listeners . As per my understanding it should work on any method , Please correct me if i am wrong and let me know if there is a way to track it